# If electrons expelled from mass increase gravity is that because they increase charge differential between mass and it's electromagnetic field?

Tags: gravity

Assuming gravity is the bending of spacetime and that it bends more around denser mass, does it bend more because the expelled electrons cause greater charge differential between the mass and any surrounding electromagnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation

But no, in any case, neither this nor gravity in general is not in any way associated with electrical charge. Neutrally charged objects such as atoms or neutrons do have mass. And Black hole evaporation does not need to rely on charged particles in particular, it can use chargeless particles too, such as photons or neutrons.